# Cannot inject EJB with@EJB annotation

Tags: annotations, ejb

Trying to inject an EJB into another one using @EJB annotation :
1) The first EJB "TestEJB" has two interfaces (AdditionRemote and AdditionLocal)
and a class implementation (Addition)

2) The second EJB "TestEJB2" has two interfaces (DivisionRemote and DivisionLocal) and a class implementation (Division)

here is the code of the "TestEJB" where i want to inject a reference of TestEJB2 :

```
    @EJB
private Division d;

public Addition() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

@Override
public void call() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    d.div(4, 2);
}
```

However when i use the @EJB annotation in the code i cannot deploy TestEJB anymore.
i get this error msg :

```
[org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"TestEJB.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"TestEJB.jar\"
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class logic.Addition with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.TestEJB.jar\" from Service Module Loader
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Labsurd/Division;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: absurd.Division from [Module \"deployment.TestEJB.jar\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
```

18:45:39,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "TestEJB.jar" with deployment "TestEJB.jar"
18:45:39,400 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."TestEJB.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "TestEJB.jar"

Answer (score 0):

you must inject one of the interfaces or add @localbean (for no-interface view) to Division

```
@EJB
private DivisionLocal d;

or

@EJB
private DivisionRemote d;
```

because the proxy is created for interfaces(when you implement interface the no-interface view will not be created for session bean unless you annotate it with @LocalBean)